# How Do I Access Network Proxy From Chroot?

Tags: debian, networking, chroot, debootstrap

I have set up `apt-cacher-ng` on my laptop

```
cat /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/02proxy 
Acquire::http { Proxy "http://localhost:3142"; };
```

I can install a package, turn off the internet, remove the package and install it again.

```
find /var/cache/apt-cacher-ng -name "*komp*"
/var/cache/apt-cacher-ng/uburep/pool/universe/k/komparator
/var/cache/apt-cacher-ng/uburep/pool/universe/k/komparator/komparator_1.0-3_amd64.deb.head
/var/cache/apt-cacher-ng/uburep/pool/universe/k/komparator/komparator_1.0-3_amd64.deb
```

However, in a chroot I can't install the same package when the internet is off.

I create the chroot like this:

```
mkdir work
cd work

#This is a backup of a previous bootstrapped using --foreign
cp ../deboot.tgz .
sudo tar -xf deboot.tgz
sudo DEBOOTSTRAP_DIR=deboot/debootstrap/ debootstrap --second-stage --second-stage-target $(readlink -f deboot)

#Set locale settings  in chroot
sudo chroot deboot locale-gen "en_US.UTF-8"
sudo chroot deboot  dpkg-reconfigure --frontend=noninteractive locales

#Set apt cache proxy in chroot
echo 'Acquire::http { Proxy "http://127.0.0.1:3142"; };' | sudo tee deboot/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/00aptproxy

# mount the /proc filesystem in the chroot (required for managing processes)
sudo mount -o bind /proc deboot/proc

sudo chroot deboot
```

Now in the chroot I do:

```
cat etc/apt/apt.conf.d/00aptproxy
Acquire::http { Proxy "http://127.0.0.1:3142"; };

root@myhostname:/# apt-get install komparator
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
E: Unable to locate package komparator
```

If I do `apt-get update` in the chroot I get the following:

```
root@myhostname:/# apt-get update
Ign:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty InRelease
Err:2 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty Release
500  Connection failure: Network is unreachable
Reading package lists... Done
E: The repository 'http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty Release' does no longer have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

How do I make the chroot install packages using apt-cacher-ng on the host?

Comment: `apt update` was missing.

Comment: Updated question with error from apt update